# How do I call ActiveRecord::Attributes::ClassMethods#columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ActiveRecord class `MyClass` with some fields in the database and which includes this concern:

```
module Wrapper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    puts self           #=> MyClass
    puts self.columns   #=> Array of ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn
  end
end
```

The first time I access this class (e.g. `MyClass.first`) I get the expected output (as above).

If I try calling `MyClass.first` a second time then no output appears, and if I run `MyClass.columns` without including the concern I get:

```
output error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for #<Object:0x007fd1f20d0ef0>>
```

Can you help me understand what's going on here?

The method in question is [ActiveRecord::Attributes::ClassMethods#columns](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb#L91-L94).

I understand that the code in the included block is [scoped to the context of the class](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects?view=asciicast) which makes sense (making this issue more mysterious).

It would also be great if you could:

- Let me know how I could have debugged it further (e.g. how do I identify which object it is that doesn't have the 'name' method)?
- Point me to any resources / tutorials that explain this concept

I'm running Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0

Comment: Is there any inheritance hierarchy regarding the classes using your `Wrapper` module?

Comment: @YanFoto that's a good question.  In fact the answer is no, but looking at it made me realise I made a mistake in my question - running `MyClass.first` a second time doesn't give an error.  I will edit my question...

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling that your problem is caused from [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb#L114)

Comment: @YanFoto yes, it would make sense that somehow when called directly this method is being called on a column without a name.

Comment: Why dont you just put a `binding.pry` before that line? It might worth a try